# Scroll View is moving horizontally and not vertically

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I have created a scroll view and I have tried many different methods as you can see below, however I always get the same outcome where the scroll view moves horizontally. I want it to move vertically, but it is not. Also, the text view shows the entire message in one line and does not use multiple lines as was happening before I added the scroll view.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices


class MainView: UIViewController {

    let transition = MainDropMenuAnimation()

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let scrollViewView = UIView()
    let factView = QuickFact()
    let socialMediaSV = SocialMediaSV()
    let logo = UIImageView()
    let aboutUs = UITextView()
    let dropMenuButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "HomeBackground"))
        addQuickFactView()
        setupScrollView()
        setupNavBar()
    }

    func setupNavBar() {
        navigationItem.title = "Home"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear

        dropMenuButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "dropMenuButton"), for: .normal)
        dropMenuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDropMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
        dropMenuButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        dropMenuButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dropMenuButton.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: dropMenuButton)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
    }

    @objc func handleDropMenu() {

        let dropMenu = DropViewContainer()
        dropMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        dropMenu.transitioningDelegate = self
        present(dropMenu, animated: true)
    }

    func addQuickFactView() {

        addChild(factView)
        view.addSubview(factView.view)
        factView.didMove(toParent: self)

        factView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        factView.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        factView.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        factView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        factView.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    }

    func setupScrollView() {
        setupView()
        scrollView.contentSize.height = 3000
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        positionScrollView()
    }
    func positionScrollView() {
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: factView.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    func setupView() {
        setupLogo()
        setupAboutUs()
        setupSocialMediaSV()
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollViewView)
        positionView()
    }
    func positionView() {
        scrollViewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollViewView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    func setupLogo() {
        logo.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Logo")
        scrollViewView.addSubview(logo)
        positionLogo()
    }
    func positionLogo() {
        logo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        logo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        logo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        logo.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        logo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    }

    func setupAboutUs() {
        let aboutUsText = (NSMutableAttributedString(string: "About Us\n", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)]))
        aboutUsText.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "At Cleaner Together, we are commited to promoting recycling, reusing, and reducing (and of course composting), while spreading sanitization and cleanliness around the world. At the moment, we are just encouraging proper waste disposal, however with proper funding we have many projects we hope to accomplish.", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]))

        aboutUs.attributedText = aboutUsText
        aboutUs.textColor = .black
        aboutUs.textAlignment = .left
        aboutUs.isScrollEnabled = false
        aboutUs.isEditable = false
        aboutUs.backgroundColor = .init(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
        aboutUs.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        scrollViewView.addSubview(aboutUs)
        positionAboutUs()
    }
    func positionAboutUs() {
        aboutUs.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        aboutUs.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewView.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        aboutUs.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewView.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        aboutUs.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        aboutUs.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logo.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    }
    func setupSocialMediaSV() {
        addChild(socialMediaSV)
        scrollViewView.addSubview(socialMediaSV.view)
        socialMediaSV.didMove(toParent: self)

        socialMediaSV.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        socialMediaSV.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        socialMediaSV.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240).isActive = true
        socialMediaSV.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutUs.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        socialMediaSV.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    }
}

extension MainView: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transition.isPresenting = true
        return transition
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transition.isPresenting = false
        return transition
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your constraints and make sure that your scroll view has correct **contentSize**.

Make scrollViewView left and right anchors also equalTo viewController's view. In func positionView()

Comment: I am so sorry. I put the wrong view controller. The correct one is there now.

Comment: Make scrollViewView left and right anchors also equalTo viewController's view. In func positionView()

Comment: But there is no common ancestor with the view controller view and the scrollViewView because I add the scrollViewView to the scrollView and then added the scrollView to the viewController view.